# How do I update the BMI value in JTable after updating the value of height and weight?

Tags: java, swing

When user insert a new height and weight, it seems the BMI value remains the same. Is there any way to get the new BMI value into the JTable? This code allows user to update their profile to see their new BMI.

```
    private void jButtonUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    String updatedheight = jTextHeight.getText();
    String updatedweight = jTextWeight.getText();
    String updatedtemperature = jTextTemperature.getText();
    String updatedDate = ((JTextField)jDateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    
    Double h = Double.parseDouble(jTextHeight.getText());
    Double w = Double.parseDouble(jTextWeight.getText());
    Double bmi = w/(h*h);
    
    System.out.println(bmi);
    if(bmi < 18.5){
       status.setText("BMI status: Underweight");
    }else if(bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <25.0){
        status.setText("BMI status: Healthy");
    }else if(bmi >= 25.0 && bmi <30){
        status.setText("BMI status: Overweight");
    }else if(bmi >= 30){
        status.setText("BMI status: Obese");
    }
    
    
    user.get(row).height = updatedheight;
    user.get(row).weight = updatedweight;
    user.get(row).temperature = updatedtemperature;
    user.get(row).date = updatedDate;
    dtm.setRowCount(0);//reset data model
    for (int i = 0; i < user.size(); i++) {
        Object[] objs = {user.get(i).height,user.get(i).weight,user.get(i).temperature,user.get(i).date,user.get(i).bmi};
        dtm.addRow(objs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: Don't keep two copies of the data. The "User" data should be stored in the TableModel of the JTable. Then you update the model with the new data by simply updating the data in the row you want to change. Don't attempt to recreate then entire table model. To create a custom TableModel check out: the step-by-step example found in [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/). Then to update the data you simply get the index of the selected row in the table and use the setValueAt(...) method of the model to update the data for the row.